# Does packages installed on root are available in virtualenv?

Tags: python, django, virtualenv

Whether i can access packages installed on root user in my virtual env while working on django project?

Comment: What happened when you tried?

Answer (score 2):

According to [`virtualenv` Docs](https://virtualenv.pypa.io/en/stable/):

> It creates an environment that has its own installation directories, that doesn’t share libraries with other virtualenv environments (and optionally doesn’t access the globally installed libraries either).

Have a look at [--system-site-packages](https://virtualenv.pypa.io/en/stable/userguide/#the-system-site-packages-option) option which gives access to the global site-packages modules to the virtual environment.

> If you build with virtualenv --system-site-packages ENV, your virtual environment will inherit packages from /usr/lib/python2.7/site-packages (or wherever your global site-packages directory is).
>
> This can be used if you have control over the global site-packages directory, and you want to depend on the packages there. If you want isolation from the global system, do not use this flag.

Hope it helps.